# How can I restrict an enum to only those adopting a protocol, which in turns depends on that enum?

Tags: swift, enums, protocols, swift-protocols

What I am trying to do is restrict the visibility of the `Taptic` enum declared in the same file as the protocol to only those files adopting the protocol. Right now, any file can "see" the enum. I have tried the combination of changing the enum's or the cases' access modifier to `fileprivate` but they are not allowed. I also have tried declaring the enum as such `enum Taptic: UInt 32 where Self: Vibratable' {` but this is not the right syntax. Any pointer?

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

enum Taptic: UInt32 {
    case Peek = 1519
    case Pop = 1520
    case Nope = 1521
}

protocol Vibratable {
    var tapticLevel: Int { get }
    func vibrateDevice(forHigherThan6s: UIImpactFeedbackStyle, for6s: Taptic, lowerThan6s: SystemSoundID)
}

extension Vibratable {
    var tapticLevel: Int {
        return UIDevice.current.value(forKey: "_feedbackSupportLevel") as! Int
    }
    func vibrateDevice(forHigherThan6s: UIImpactFeedbackStyle = .medium, for6s: Taptic = .Peek, lowerThan6s: SystemSoundID = kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) {
        switch tapticLevel {
        case 2:
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: forHigherThan6s)
            generator.prepare()
            generator.impactOccurred()
        case 1:
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(for6s.rawValue)
        default:
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(lowerThan6s)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want all files to see the enum?

Comment: Hi! I can't understand the problem with using a fileprivate enum...

Comment: @Sweeper just tyring to scope access only to those who adopts the protocol. Otherwise the enum is actually "useless" without the protocol.